# How to detect if global variable is a string in LLVM?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-c++-api

In earlier releases of llvm/clang I was able to detect whether global variable was a string by using ie. the GlobalVar->getName() function and checking whether it ends with ".str". I've tried this in the llvm/clang 13 and 14 and it seems that all the names I'm getting are mangled names. Am I missing something?

For example, I have this basic C source code:

```
//compiled with: clang.exe -std=c99 helloCC.c -o helloCC.exe -mllvm -my_get_strings=1 -flegacy-pass-manager

#include <stdio.h>

char *xmy1 = "hello world";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   printf("%s", xmy1);
   return 0;
}
```

I've manually edited the llvm/clang code too trigger my function as one of the pass (clang executed with "-flegacy-pass-manager" and I've added my pass to PassManagerBuilder.cpp int the void PassManagerBuilder::populateModulePassManager(legacy::PassManagerBase &MPM) function.

Anyway my runOnModule handler executes, iterates over global variables (M.global_being() to M.global_end()) and all the names got by GlobalVar->getName()  seems to be mangled:

`found global = "??_C@_0M@LACCCNMM@hello?5world?$AA@"`

Obviously now my previous theory to detect whether this is a string or not doesn't work. Is there any other better function to detect whether a global is a string / or I am doing something wrong?

I've tried demangling the name, well I can demangle it but I still don't know how to verify whether this is a string or nor. Is there any LLVM function for it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main question here is what do you mean by "global variable is string". If you're meaning C-style strings, then you'd just take initializer (which is `Constant`) and check if this is a C-style string using `isCString` method (https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantDataSequential.html#aecff3ad6cfa0e4abfd4fc9484d973e7d)